# Symfony3 / Doctrine - function: adding row with foreign key

Tags: php, doctrine, foreign-key-relationship, symfony

I am just starting the adventure with Symfony3 (and with php) and I encountered a problem.

At this moment my application is supposed to allow user to CRUD his projects. Displaying works fine, but I have a problem with creating.

I have got two tables: users and projects.
Project table contains all project data including **project owner** which is basically the ID of user. 
Thanks to Symfony docs I managed to map both tables:

### part of "Project" entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="projects")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="uid", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $uid;


/**
 * Set uid
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $uid
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setUid(\AppBundle\Entity\User $uid = null)
{
    $this->uid = $uid;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get uid
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\User
 */
public function getUid()
{
    return $this->uid;
}
```

### part of 'User' entity:

```
private $projects;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->projects = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

At this point I'm able to display full project info, i.e. project title + project owner details. 
The problem starts with implementation of basic function like Creating new project.

I was following that doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#saving-related-entities. 
The thing is - I don't want to create new User as well, just assign existing user to new project.
To do that I've created a new function in project controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/projects/create/", name="project_create")
 */
public function createProject()
{
    $project = new Project();
    $project->setTitle('WebProject');
    $project->setDescription('asdfghjkgfdsadfghgfdsdfg');
    $project->setLogo('asdf');
    $project->setCreatedat(time());
    $project->setDateline('-');

    // relate this product to the category
    $project->setUid(1);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($project);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response(
        'Saved new product with id: '.$project->getId()
    );
}
```

This function was supposed to add new project and set User with id 1 to be an owner of project. As I could expect it doesn't work.
The error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\Project::setUid() must be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\User, integer given, called in...

Well, indeed, that's true. But I've no idea how to pass there a instance of User with it's ID.

Thanks!

Comment: $userReference = $entityManager->getReference('Bundle:User',$userId);  $project->setUser($userReference).  Doctrine Object Relation Manager (ORM) is quite different than the active record stuff with which I suspect you are more familiar with.  Go through the examples in the documentation and perhaps read a few tutorials.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing. Just to much things to read and remember at once as for the beggining.
Got it to work, thanks you! :)